# jquery/javascript creating a logout timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to create a timer that will log my clients out when they have been idol for over 10 minutes.  I have created the code below which works fine as long as the user does not open a second tab.  I have many clients that open a second window or tab and while the second tab is open the counter speeds up. I am looking for a way to improve the following code so that the tabs/windows can be in better sync.

```
var cookies='off'; // var to check if cookies are turned off
var alertTimes=0; // alturnative to cookies
$(function(){
    resetCookies();
    var loginTime=getCookie("loginTime");
    if (loginTime!=null && loginTime!=""){ cookies='on'; }
    checkAlerts();
});

function resetCookies(){
    setCookie("loginTime",'10',1);
    alertTimes=0;
}
function checkTime() {
    if(cookies=='on'){
        var loginTime=getCookie("loginTime");
        if (loginTime!=null && loginTime!=""){ 
            var newTime=loginTime-1;
            if(newTime==0){ autoLogout(); return false;}
            setCookie("loginTime",newTime,1);
        }else{ autoLogout(); return false;}
    }else{
        alertTimes++;
        if(alertTimes>=10){ autoLogout(); return false;}
    }
    setTimeout(checkTime, 600000);
}
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
function getCookie(c_name){
  var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
  for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++){
    x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
    x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    if (x==c_name){ return unescape(y); }
  }
}
function autoLogout(){
    window.location.href=("logout.php");
}
```

Comment: How does your code detect whether the user was "idle" for 10 minutes? From what I understand, it just decrements the counter by 1 every minute since the page loaded. The user could very well be using the page for 10 minutes and he would logged out.

Comment: Ideally what you need is to track the activity of the user. This could be as simple has having a mouse move handler or keyup handler. If either is triggered, update the time in the cookie to current time. Your checktime function then simply reads the time from the cookie and checks whether 10 minutes has passed since then. If so, logout.

Comment: It could also get as sophisticated as using a combination of client side tracking and server side tracking. Chances are any action the user takes on your page will hit the server, log that time, store it on the server and also return it to be stored in the cookie. At every server access check if the users stored last access was over 10 minutes ago. If so, block that access and logout the user. This ensures your 10 min idle logout rule even if the user manages to bypass the js checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this example will satisfy your needs?

```
( function ( $ ) {
  $.loginTimeout = function ( options ) {

    var opts = $.extend( {}, $.loginTimeout.defaults, options ),
    callback = function() {
      $.getJSON( opts.url, function ( data ) {
        if(data.status === "signed_out")
        document.location = opts.redirectTo;
      });
    };
    setInterval( callback, opts.timeout * 1000 );
  };

  $.loginTimeout.defaults = {
    timeout: 60,
    redirectTo: "/login",
    url: "/check_login"
  };
} ( jQuery ) );
// ...
$.loginTimeout({
  redirectTo: "/users/sign_in",
  url: "/users/check_status"
});
```

also keep in mind that in this example server application is deciding if user session has expired

Comment: At the server side you can create a session variable that store the user's login time and find the difference between the two times.

Comment: How does this keep two pages from reporting in and speeding it up?  The point is to update the timer every time the page loads. I do not wish to triple my bandwidth by creating unnecessary queries. This site has to many users.

Comment: I understand that every new tab will give you 10 minutes again, in this case you don't have to worry that time is not synchronized in two tabs. If you want to fetch time left you can just add it to response

Answer (score 0):

The code you gave was almost there.  I needed the same thing for my code.  I added information to the cookie (last time modified) and compare that to the current time.  If there is enough space in between (in this case 1 second) then modify the cookie info.  This works even if you have 15 tabs open.
*I took out the check for whether they have cookies turned on.*

```
$(function(){
    resetCookies();
    setTimeout(checkTime, 1000);
});

function resetCookies(){
    setCookie("loginTime",'10',1);
}
function checkTime() {

    var arrloginTime=getCookie("loginTime").split("--");
    var loginTime=arrloginTime[0];
    var dtmLastMod=new Date(arrloginTime[1]);
    console.log(loginTime);
    if (loginTime!=null && loginTime!=""){ 
        var dtmNow = new Date();
        if ((dtmNow.getTime() - dtmLastMod.getTime()) >= 1000){
            var newTime=loginTime-1;
            if(newTime==0){ autoLogout(); return false;}
            setCookie("loginTime",newTime,1);
        }
    }else{ autoLogout(); return false;}
    setTimeout(checkTime, 1000);
}
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
    var exdate=new Date();
    var dtmLastMod = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + "--" + dtmLastMod + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
function getCookie(c_name){
  var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
  for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++){
    x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
    x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    if (x==c_name){ return unescape(y); }
  }
}
function autoLogout(){
    console.log('You have been logged out of this document due to inactivity.');
}
```